# Debug/reproduce EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in CA::release_objects

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, exc-bad-access

I use Crashlytics to track crashes and I am seeing some crashes with the stack trace below:

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf8560b1c

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37a20b66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2d5f8e8d CFRelease + 560
2  QuartzCore                     0x2fad2965 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 16
3  QuartzCore                     0x2fad7dcf -[CAAnimation dealloc] + 54
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37a30b0b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2d5f8e8d CFRelease + 560
6  QuartzCore                     0x2fada419 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 240
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x37f0a0af _dispatch_client_callout + 22
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x37f0c9a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 268
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2d6935b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2d691e7d __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2d5fc471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2d5fc253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x323362eb GSEventRunModal + 138
14 UIKit                          0x2feb1845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

It looks like CFRelease is being called on some object twice. The problem is I have no idea which animation is causing the crash. The logs aren't very helpful as the crash happens in different places. How do I go about debugging/reproducing this crash or at the very least logging something so that I know what object is being released twice.

Comment: Do you have any CAAnimations with delegates?

Comment: I wouldn't interpret the callstack as CFRelease being called on some object twice.  More like CFRelease is being called, which triggers stuff that leads to another calling of CFRelease.  The latter CFRelease is sending a message to an object that's not too happy about it, and causes a crash.

Comment: @matt I do not use CAAnimation directly anywhere in my code. I do have a number of places which use: [UIView animateWithDuration]

Comment: @KirkSpaziani The crash I see is: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf8560b1c. Which according to my understanding is accessing deallocated memory and hence crashing. Does that not imply that CFRelease is being called on a deallocated object?

Comment: Well, @KirkSpaziani is clearly right in the sense that the CFRelease of this object is _causing_ the CFRelease of this object again. That is why I asked you about animation delegates. It is almost as if you had some circularity where something to do with the animation has a property which is itself - so when it is released, it releases that thing which is again itself and so we get the bad access.

Comment: If you could just reproduce the crash you could instantly figure out what object this is, simply by having turned on NSZombies. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: I agree with @matt, FYI in XCode 6.0 I've has issues getting the Enable Zombie's scheme option to work. But you can work around it by setting the environment variable NSZombieEnabled=YES

Comment: Yes @matt. If I had a way to reproduce it, enabling Zombies would be the best way to figure out what is wrong. The problem is that the crash occurs in the wild and is relatively rare. I only get the stack trace and the associated logs. Is there some way for me to log additional information when this crash happens, so that I can repro it?

Comment: Have you tried lldb to print the backtrace (bt) and registers (reg read)? That might helps you. I usually check the trace, and add some NSLog in suspecious code, and continue debugging

Comment: I recommend run Profiler with memory tool and diligently check your animations. Probably you will see some issues or leaks.

Comment: @Wingzero Can you elaborate more or point me to a reference? The stack trace is one that I get from crash reports not something I see in the debugger.